# Getting Error 404 while running npm install create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Getting error `404` while running `npm install create-react-app` or `npm install -g npm@latest`.

Log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'create-react-app' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.3
4 verbose npm-session 1f3eafc1b2f09e93
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 66ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for create-react-app@latest 404 Not Found: create-react-app@latest
9 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: create-react-app@latest
9 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
9 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
9 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
9 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
9 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
9 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
10 verbose cwd M:\Projects\TestApps\ReactApp
11 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
12 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "create-react-app"
13 verbose node v8.11.3
14 verbose npm  v5.6.0
15 error code E404
16 error 404 Not Found: create-react-app@latest
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: npm v - 5.6.0  and node v - v8.11.3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First check if is a **Proxy Issue**.

Try to **install** the package with **another internet connection**!

***Another causes***

**Missing repository registry**

`$ npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

**Clean cache**

```
$ npm cache clean
$ npm rebuild
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But I am getting bellow error - npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: npm@latest

Comment: Can you try with other internet net? So we discard the chance of firewall configuration??

Comment: Thanks Eugenio. It was proxy issue. I updated proxy and registry now its working. :)

Comment: Good to help! I modified my answer so you can mark as approved and help other people :)

Comment: @VivekFutane Was this the solution??

Comment: yest, but now I am getting new error while starting npm - npm ERR! missing script: start

Comment: That means that you are not in the folder where the package.json is!

Comment: Can you add to your post your package json if you are in the correct place?

Answer (score 2):

My problem also same but when I try following commands then works fine

If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, I recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

Then reinstall using

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the current version of npm and install the latest version using

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Answer (score 1):

The newest way to do this would be to use `npx`.

```
npx create-react-app my-app [...options]
```

I use this method because I also use `nvm` to manage `node` installs. Everything just plays nice with this method.

Answer (score 0):

You have already installed the npm create-react-app globally. You can just write

```
 npm init react-app *projectFolderName*
```

and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem for almost a week here is my simple solution if you are using windows

1. run cmd as  admin.
2. put this url `npm config set registry https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry` on cmd.
3. then type `npx create-react-app@latest **YourProjectName**`

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting my code editor did the job

Answer (score 0):

1, npm cache verify
2, npm rebuild
3, npm uninstall -g create-react-app
4, npm install -g create-react-app
5, npx create-react-app

Answer (score -3):

You can try this command, which has worked for me:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```