# npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/creat-react-app - Not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

This error has happened before and solutions have been found (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8465, [Getting Error 404 while running npm install create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238540/getting-error-404-while-running-npm-install-create-react-app/54238603)). None of them seem to work for me. Any other ideas?

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/creat-react-app - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'creat-react-app@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-09-05T12_21_39_255Z-debug.log
Install for creat-react-app@latest failed with code 1
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You searched for **creat**-react-app, not **create**-react-app. (creat**e**)