# Not able to install bootstrap version 5.1.3 using npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@5.1.3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-install, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

These are the errors that are returnend. I need help help fixing them so I can continue my project for my institute

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-bootsrtap - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'react-bootsrtap@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jaund\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-12-11T07_09_08_861Z-debug.log

Comment: Can you post what is in `C:\Users\jaund\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-12-11T07_09_08_861Z-debug.log`

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238540/getting-error-404-while-running-npm-install-create-react-app/54238603

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.